# PDF document generated using itext# opens in Foxit but not Acrobat

Tags: pdf, itext, acrobat, foxit

My application is generating PDF documents using itext#. The files open fine and display correctly in *Foxit Reader* but in *Adobe Acrobat* it errors with:

```
There was an error processing page. There was a problem reading this document (109).
```

Why will the file open in one but not the other?

Comment: also, apart from the above message when opening the document in Acrobat Reader, the Internet Explorer Acrobat Reader add-on / extension viewer that opens by default when requesting the PDF in question from a server, would give me the following message (code after Local\ sometimes changing) :

Object label badly formatted.
Local\EWH-1884-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was my code:

```
        var document = new Document(_pageSize, PageMargin, PageMargin, PageMargin, PageMargin);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        writer.PageEvent = new Footer(HeaderFont, _defaultFont.BaseFont, report.Name);
        document.Open();

        if (report.Results.Any())
            document.Add(CreateTable(report.Results, report.Types, report.RootType));
        else
            document.Add(new Paragraph("No results", _defaultFont));

        writer.Close();
```

After adding the line `document.Close();` before the `writer.Close();` line, it now shows in both *Foxit* and *Acrobat*.

I guess a key thing with itext# is to be very careful that objects are closed properly. This probably reflects it is a ported library and not a library built for .NET from the ground up.

Comment: Adding the line document.Close() before the writer.Close() caused program to crash. writer.Close() expects the document to still be available.

Comment: As in all exemples from the itext book, use Document.close(). PdfWriter.close() is not needed, and cause the resulting pdf to be corrupted.

Comment: in my case, I was wrapping both Document & PdfWriter in <using> clauses - I feel that some kind of Close might be called along with implicit Dispose, as the result of the <using>, on PdfWriter - I got rid of <using> and moved explicit calls to Dispose, both for Document & PdfWriter, to finally block - the problem got solved, thanks to this thread

Comment: It worked when I removed writer.close(). Thanks it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Some pdf readers are more tolerant in various areas than others.  Foxit probably ignores bits in a pdf that it doesn't support.  Different versions of acrobat choke on different things, just to muddy the waters.  Without seeing the PDF in question, all we've got is guesswork.